# In Subversion, I know when a file was added, what's the quickest way to find out when it was deleted?

Tags: svn

OK, so suppose I know I added file "foo.txt" to my Subversion repository at revision 500.

So I can do a `svn log -v http://svnrepo/path/foo.txt@500`, and that shows all the files added at the same time.

What's the fastest way to find when the file was deleted after it was added?

I tried `svn log -r500:HEAD -v http://svnrepo/path/foo.txt@500`, but that gives me "path not found" - perhaps obviously, because the file "foo.txt" doesn't exist at "HEAD".

I can try a binary search algorithm going forward through revisions (and that would certainly be faster than typing this question), but is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Try running

```
svn log -v http://svnrepo/path/
```

That should give you (among other things) the revision when files were deleted in that directory. "grep" may also be useful if the output is large.